# How to find a context-free grammar from a difficult language?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, formal-grammars

Some Languages are trivial to find their respective context-free grammar. Like for example $ L= \{a^nb^n: n \geqslant 0\}$. However some are really difficult to solve. I would like to have some advice on how I can tackle them.

For example I have the following language that I have been trying to solve for a while :[image]

I tried to divide the problem into three cases as follow:

case i: n<sub>a</sub> $\le$ n<sub>b</sub>

case ii: n<sub>b</sub> $\le$ n<sub>a</sub> $<$ 2n<sub>b</sub>

case iii: n<sub>a</sub> $\ge$ 2n<sub>b</sub>

The first case was easy to solve however I am stuck in case ii. At this point I don't even know if the procedure that I chose is the correct one.

EDIT: It is not an duplicate 3 of the links that you have provided me are not the same problem one of them is the same suggests the same strategy however doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @D.W.♦ It is not an duplicate 3 of the links that you have provided me are not the same problem one of them is the same suggests the same strategy however doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You should be able to adapt the methods there; it's the same idea.  Hint: build a PDA.